# VisioIsIdle is never called?

Tags: vba, visio

When is VisioIsIdle event being called? Is my code for the event correct? Because the ToolApp_VisioIsIdle is not being called. I plan on using VisioIsIdle event to close the application if it satisfy some condition.

```
Dim ToolApp As Visio.Application

Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument) 
    Set ToolApp = Visio.Application
End Sub 

Private Sub ToolApp_VisioIsIdle(ByVal app As IVApplication)
    Debug.Print "Idle"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried running a sub in the same object to set the ToolApp object to Visio.Application, and seeing if it works. That'd just separate out whether it's a problem of DocumentOpened being called, and VisioIsIdle being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem by adding WithEvents when declaring the variable ToolApp.

```
Dim WithEvents ToolApp As Visio.Application

Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As IVDocument) 
    Set ToolApp = Visio.Application
End Sub 

Private Sub ToolApp_VisioIsIdle(ByVal app As IVApplication)
    Debug.Print "Idle"
End Sub
```